# How can I make a comment on another answer when I have less than 50 reputation

Tags: support, reputation, comments, rejected-edits

So, over at [Best way to combine two or more byte arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415291/best-way-to-combine-two-or-more-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp) there's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415291/best-way-to-combine-two-or-more-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp/#21426859) that builds on one of the other answers to offer a "generic" c# method for concatenating arrays.

That code contains some serious and dangerous bugs (it'll only end up copying part of the data in most cases).

So I figure I'll provide some constructive feedback ... but I can't comment. What to do? I'll edit the errant post and add a note explaining exactly what the problems with the code are and how they might be fixed. Fixing the code is a challenge though - and may not actually be possible - so I don't offer a full code listing.

A moderator then denies the edit with a note saying that feedback on other posts is best done with a comment (I agree, and I would if I could) or by adding another answer of your own.

"Fine then" I think, so I spend some more time making an even more detailed submission as an answer. I reference the name of the person who posted the original comment in my answer and post.

**Now my answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415291/best-way-to-combine-two-or-more-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp/#32528678) if you have enough reputation to see it) has been deleted - for reasons unknown.**

What am I supposed to do in this case? Stack Overflow has been so useful to me so many times that occasionally I like to give a little something back - but you guys are really making it hard!

I mean is the only solution *really* to trawl around trying to find questions to answer and scratch up enough reputation to come back some day in the future and make a comment?

As a side note I think it's a little cruel to simply delete a constructive post with no feedback to the author. As any of you with high reputations would know, it takes valuable time to put together an informative post. It would be nice if the answer moderation scheme at least listed a reason for the deletion - like the mechanism for rejecting edits seems to.

Comment: Earn more rep to earn the privilege to comment - you are almost there and your contributions are well written - should not take you too long at all.

Comment: Looks like you are there now! A positive meta effect in action. Keep writing good posts!

Comment: Well thanks santiago. Are you just being completely dismissive (and rather entitled because you've spent enough of your life answering questions here to have over 50 rep)? Or are you simply being completely pragmatic and telling me it's useless to even try to work around being a second-class citizen here?

Comment: @santiago Ahhh thanks :) I guess it was the latter (pragmatic). Sorry - it's very hard to tell within the confines of a short comment - and I'm tired and emotional right now! (that's not a euphemism for being drunk though)

Comment: Actually, neither - merely noting that your contributions are very good and would get you over the 50 needed in no time at all. When I read a couple of your answers, it led me to that conclusion (and I upvoted a couple of them). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ahh, well in that case - let me thank you again :) ... I s'pose I'll go off and do one last copy/paste into a comment now!

Comment: Can you not actually answer with a correct (non-dangerous) answer and at the end of that state the problem with doing it another way?

Comment: Hi Robert. I guess that could have been a possibility - maybe I could have taken the code with the bug and done the easy fix (which would have been to replace all the Buffer.BlockCopy calls with Array.Copy calls). It would have resulted in less performance than what the person who wrote the code was looking for, but it would have worked. Fortunately, santiago helped me just over the required reputation limit and I was able to re-post it all as comments on the errant answer.  ...

Comment: The issue remains though, that I'm not really sure why my answer was deleted? (and this sort of thing is bound to frustrate other new users). Is the problem that the answer wasn't a complete answer (as it talked entirely about another answer)? There was absolutely no feedback to say why it was deleted, so I can only guess.